# How to replace multiple row values with group names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert day names to 'workday' or 'weekend'.my column is like this

```
0         Saturday
1         Saturday
2         Saturday
3         Saturday
4         Saturday
            ...   
209526      Friday
209527      Friday
209528      Friday
209529      Friday
209530      Friday
```

and I want this

```
0         Weekend
1         Weekend
2         Weekend
3         Weekend
4         Weekend            
             ...   
209526      Workday
209527      Workday
209528      Workday
209529      Workday
209530      Workday
```

My code which returns nothing:

```
df['Weekday_Or_Workday'] = df.replace(["Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"],["Workday","Workday","Workday","Workday","Workday","Weekend","Weekend"])
```

How can I make this conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df['Weekday_Or_Workday'] = df['Weekday_Or_Workday'].map({'Monday':'Workday','Tuesday':'Workday','Wednesday':'Workday','Thursday':'Workday','Friday':'Workday','Saturday':'Weekend','Sunday':'Weekend'})
```

Answer (score 4):

I copied your line of code and it worked for me.

Since that line of code is setting one object equal to another, it won't *return* anything.

If you now run `df` (or `print(df)`), you should see that the column has been added.

edit: here is the dataframe I started with:

`df = pd.DataFrame(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])`

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap a `dict(zip(..` to your code, it might be more readable:

```
import calendar

days = calendar.day_name
to_replace = *["Workday"]*5, *["Weekend"]*2

df["Weekday_Or_Workday"] = df.replace(dict(zip(days, to_replace)))
```